# Swagger shows "Failed to fetch" error but works fine in Postman (API gateway)

Tags: node.js, swagger, aws-api-gateway, swagger-2.0, swagger-editor

I'm new to Swagger. I have created a aws API gateway. When I try to run that using swagger I get this error

Failed to fetch.
Possible Reasons:

- CORS
- Network Failure
- URL scheme must be "http" or "https" for CORS request.

[image: This is the error in swagger]

But when I copy the curl and import it in postman it works fine. It works fine in postman but I get errors in swagger. Can anyone help me with this?
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Check if CORS is tuned correctly on backend because Postman doesn't send preflight requests

Comment: @Anatoly You mean these right?
    Access-Control-Allow-Origin', Access-Control-Allow-Methods', Access-Control-Allow-Headers'

Comment: What is the full error message on the Console tab in the browser dev tools?

Comment: Usually, CORS is tuned by adding `cors` middleware package, maybe along with indicating some additional non-default parameters

Answer (score 2):

```
@OpenAPIDefinition(servers = {@Server(url = "/", description = "Default Server URL")})
```

In Springboot, you have to configure the default server and in case you have context in your application you have to add it as follwing:

```
@OpenAPIDefinition(servers = {@Server(url = "/", description = "Default Server URL"), @Server(url = "/myapp", description = "MyAPP Server URL")})
```

Comment: Please, add some explanations.

Comment: In Springboot you have to configre the default server and in case you have context in your application you have to add it as follwing:@OpenAPIDefinition(servers = {@Server(url = "/", description = "Default Server URL"), @Server(url = "/myapp", description = "MyAPP Server URL")})

Comment: @AhmedElRewenyWhy do we have to do it? How does it work?